# How to draw a line between two images in android?

Tags: android

I need to implement a program to join an image from one column to other column. I need do the next:
link: http://imageshack.us/a/img217/6163/exampleoz.png

I have tried with drag and drop ([android developers drag and drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)) but it isn't what I need because with drag and drop you move the image from one location to another and I don't want to move anything.
I want that when you press one image on the screen, without lifting the finger, and then you move your finger to other image and lift the finger, the two images are matched.

**Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: Specifically what part are you having trouble with? Creating a blended image, telling if the images match... or what?

Comment: ok, sorry! I have already created all the user interface with all images. I have five images in one column and other 5 images in other column. Now, I need to implement the gesture that I mentioned earlier. I want to "match" the pictures, I don't want to merge the images. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onTouchEvent()` :

On `ACTION_DOWN` store first position (`event.getX()`, `event.getY()`)

On `ACTION_UP` store second position.

Draw a line between those 2 points.

Comment: thank you very much.
I suppose with this method I can know which image is "join" with other, because the method is launched when I press the first image and stopped when I lift the finger on the second image,no? To save the image data, in this case, the amount which they represent. Knowing the amount of the first image in ACCTION_DOWN and know the amount of the second in ACCTION_UP. Or get the values ​​of quantities depending on the coordinates?